# Prove that $<a>$ (Cyclic subgroup of $G$ generated by $a$) is a subgroup of $G$

Tags: group-theory

I am trying to prove $<a>$ is a subgroup of $G$ using the One-Step Subgroup Test.

**The One-Step Subgroup Test**
Let $G$ be a subgroup and $H$ a non-empty subset of $G$. We say $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ if $\alpha \beta ^{-1} \in H$ whenever $\alpha,\beta \in H$.

We need to solve the 4-steps involved in the one-step subgroup test

1) Identify the property that distinguishes elements of H

2) Show that the identity has the property

3) Assume 2 elements $\alpha,\beta$ have the property

4) Using the assumption, show that $\alpha \beta^{-1}$ has the property

So the claim is $<a>$ is a subgroup of $G$.

**My Proof**

Step 1: The defining property of $<a>$ is $a \in G$ and $a^n : n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Step 2: Now, we want to show that the identity holds true given the property. Since $a \in <a>$, we know that $<a>$ is not empty.

Step 3: Assume $a^n, a^m \in <a>$ such that $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Step 4: Notice that $a^n(a^m)^{-1} = a^{n-m}$. Since $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $a^{n-m} \in <a>$ (by definition of $<a>$).

Hence, by the One-Step Subgroup Test, $<a>$ is a subgroup of $G$.

My problem here is first, in the step 1. I am not sure how to write the defining property of $<a>$. I am also not sure of step 2. I know the identity of $<a>$ is reached by some $a^i = e$. But I don't know how to express it. I really appreciate your help. Thank you

Comment: You've shown that the identity is in $\langle a\rangle$, but not at step 2, but step 4. I don't know what exactly you want to do in step 2, but if it is to show $\langle a\rangle\neq\emptyset$, then it is ok,

Comment: Well, I am suppose to show that $<a>$ is nonempty at some point. I did that at step 2. But, I am having a problem expressing that the identity is in $<a>$, instead, I said $a$ is in $<a>$. If you know what I mean. $a$ is not the identity of $<a>$, its some element of $<a>$ with $a^i = e$ and $e \in G$

Comment: What is $a^n$ when $n$ is chosen as the integer zero?

Comment: You know you gave me an idea, not sure if it will work tho. The identity of $<a>$ can be written by taking any element multiplied by its inverse. For example $a^n(a^n)^{-1}$

Comment: Man, thank you. I feel stupid :) a^0 is the identity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** $\langle a\rangle = \{ a^n\in G\,|\, n\in\Bbb Z\}$

**2.** $e = a^0 \in \langle a\rangle$

**3., 4.** Looks good.

Also, step 2 is implied by step 4, take $a$ and $a^-1$ in $\langle a\rangle$ and multiply them.

Comment: Thank you man, I got it now.